# distinct() method doesn't work with values() in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I am following Mosh's Django course, and I followed him step by step untill I get stack in this issue here, for him it works fine, but for me it doesn't work, I can't call distanct() method from values() why is that? I have searched in Django documentation and I found nothing I thought may they update it ,Igoogled it too but I haven't found an answer yet, could any one here help me ?

`queryset = OrderItem.objects.values('product_id').distinct()`

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I can't call distinct() method from values() to get rid of duplicated values, it doesn't work for me but it work for Mosh!

Comment: does it throw any errors?

Comment: I found this in django documentation
[Link ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) **distinct()**

Comment: When using **distinct()** and **values()** together, be careful when ordering by fields not in the **values()** call from [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)